# dropping string from a series based on character length with list comprehension Python

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I have this series in a dataframe of **df**:

```
column1                     column2   column3
needs n before mi toilets   2013      sport
```

I want to drop string in **column1** with character counts below 4 times so that my dataframe would look like this:

```
column1               column2   column3
needs before toilets   2013      sport
```

I tried list simple for loop with this code:

```
for i in df['column1'].str.split():
    for j in i:
        if len(j) < 4:
            df['column1'].drop(j)
```

but I got error saying:

```
"['n'] not found in axis"
```

I also tried to simplify the code to list comprehension, but so far I don't get the good code. This is my attempt to do that **but with print (j) as my output**:

```
 [print(j) for i in df['column1'].str.split() for j in df['column1'] if len(j) < 4]
```

and I got no return for that code.

Anyone has any idea why? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas.Series.str.findall` with `join`:

```
df['column1'].str.findall('\w{4,}').str.join(' ')
```

Output:

```
0    needs before toilets
Name: column1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['column1'] = ' '.join(j for i in df.column1 for j in i.split() if len(j)>4)

print(df)
          column1         column2 column3
0  needs before toilets     2013   sport
```

Comment: An explanation of the solution would make this a batter answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete solution  using the str join from pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"column1":["needs n before mi toilets"],"column2": 
                                     ["2013"],"column3": ["sport"]})
df["column1"] = df['column1'].str.findall('\w{4,}').str.join(' ')
```

now the data frame contains the updated string in column1